# Topographic differencing using lidar

Tags: topography

I have two lidar images which I want to use to do a topographic differencing. The two lidar images are of different spatial resolutions and are not co-registered. What is the best method to line the two images up to perform the topographic differencing (by resampling to same the spatial resolution and co-registering the layers)?

Comment: For co-registration, you can try the Python script demcoreg: https://github.com/dshean/demcoreg